# Can I execute the number stored in a register as an instruction in MIPS?

Tags: mips, self-modifying

If I take an instruction and break it down into the binary representation of its op code, rs, rt etc... could I then put this binary number into a register and get MIPS to treat it as an instruction?

For example:

The instruction:  `add $t0, $s0, $t0`

Breaks down to:

`000000 10010 01000 01000 00000 100000`

Which corresponds to the integer: 18696

Could I store this integer in a register, and then get MIPS to treat it as an instruction?

I ask this with the idea of self-modifying code in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct answer is - **no**. As pointed out in a comment by a user who read the question more carefully than I did the first time, the value must be first written to memory, then you load an address value of the memory where that value is stored, and then you jump to it.

You may want to explore more how [JIT compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) work, as they use a lot of code modification (to be clear, they do not modify the code generator, but they do a lot of live patching of the generated code during the execution).

Comment: This is nonsense. No modern CPU can feed the current value of a register into its instruction decoder and execute it.  The value you want to execute as an instruction must be written to memory. JIT compilers do not modify themselves, they dynamically create blocks of code in memory and cause the program being compiled to branch to and execute them.

Comment: @markgz

You are absolutely correct. I have read the question incorrectly, and thus I gave the wrong answer. Thank you.